# Is it possible to read data from a Oracle View and insert it into MYSQL tables?

Tags: php, mysql, oracle

I am working on a website, built using PHP and MySQL database, on the website I have to read data from an ORACLE view and insert it into MySQL tables for further processing using PHP.
Is it possible to do so? Any heads up?

I have the necessary information of Oracle db and view to connect and read the view

Comment: I don't see why not. What isn't working exactly?

Comment: I have no idea where to start from..

Comment: Step 1: Find some questions on stackoverflow that asks how to read from oracle using php. Copy the code you like most. Step 2: Find some question on stackoverflow that asks how to insert data into MySQL using php, ideally using the same libraries (msqli or pdo) as in step 1. Copy the code you like most. Step 3: Combine those two steps by using the output of step 1 as input for step 2.  Step 4: If you run into problems, post your code attempt with a problem description (e.g. an error message, ask how to combine the steps properly or if you did it properly or if it can be done faster, ...)

Comment: One option worth looking at is to use MYSQL (MariaDB) ODBC Connect. This will allow you access Oracle tables from MYSQL. It requires configuration on the MYSQL server side to create the DSN, and an account on Oracle that the DSN use for the connection. See this:  https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/